# manage session after refresh page in WebRTC based audio calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, html5-audio

I am currently using a [Kandy WebRTC library](https://github.com/Kandy-IO/kandy-link-js-sdk)  to make WebRTC based audio calls. As this JavaScript library internally using the WebSocket the problem I am facing is to keep the session alive if the user refreshes the page.

For example, when a user A connects via Kandy library and makes a call to user B and during the call if the user refreshes the page the connection lost at user A but user B is still on call as it is not properly ended by user A. The hurdle is Kandy library does not provide a way to re-connect to an ongoing call.

Hence, I want to know is there anything that we could do on a client-side to manage this refresh page issue. One of the approaches that came into my mind is to shift the JavaScript Client + `Kandy` logic to the `Node.js` server and access the make call and receive calls using `HTTP` services. But I am really not sure how the audio would work in this case because this `Kandy library` requires the rendering media or `<audio>` tag to establish the media channel.

Here is the [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/ntimesc/pen/RwPwQjv) just to understand the code, due to security reason I won't be able to provide the credentials but you can have the jest of code that we have used for the sample.

Check the  `kandy.media.renderTracks(call.remoteTracks, "#remote-container")` which requires the `div` tag   `<div id="remote-container"></div>` to render the media.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a bug in the Kandy SDK. Typically the signalling server (in this case a websocket) can detect if a client that is in a call closes the websocket and notify the other end of the call.

Using [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to send a clientside "bye" might help too.

Comment: is there any way to restore it rather than end it